# jQuery focus on the first input , first input is Disable then it is going to oustide the browser

Tags: jquery, focus, user-input, disabled-input

Focus will set to the first control while screen opening,But When the
 First Control Disabled means  focus need to set for the next
control.But it is going to oustide the browser

i tried this code

```
 $('#AddNewTab input:enabled:first').focus();


$('#AddNewTab :input:enabled:visible:not([disable]):first').focus();




 $("#AddNewTab").find('input, textarea,text, select')
 .not('input[type=enabled],input[type=button],input[type=submit],input[type=reset],input[type=image],button')
     .filter(':enabled:visible:first')
      .focus();
```

jQuery focus on the first input  , first input is Disable then it is going to oustide the browser

pls help me....

Comment: Please show an example of your page HTML too

Answer (score 0):

The following fiddle will solve your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/aalok/uw2hozxw/

you need to change your code to this  `$("#AddNewTab input:first-child:disabled").next().focus();`